# Akka Scheduler Not Running On Designated Schedule

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I have an Akka scheduler which is supposed to call a function every 100 milliseconds. However, instead it calls the function once every 15 seconds or so. I can't understand why it's running, but not on the designated schedule.

The code looks like

```
class Application @Inject()(implicit system: ActorSystem, db: Database,
                            materializer: Materializer, comm: WebSocketCommunicator) extends Controller {

  val sqs = new PollSQSDataToDatabase(db)

  Logger.info("Starting scheduler at " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString)

  system.scheduler.schedule(Duration.Zero, Duration(100, "millis"))(pollData)

  def pollData = {
    Logger.info("Poll data called at " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString)
    sqs.getData()
  }
}
```

So, "Checking..." gets outputted, but way too slowly.

**EDIT**

I added it to print the timestamp, and this is what gets outputted. As you can see, it calls `pollData` every 10 seconds.

> [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:29:39.809
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:29:50.802
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:30:00.82
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:30:10.9
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:30:20.921
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:30:30.939
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:30:40.959
>   [info] application - Poll data called at 2016-08-10 11:30:50.991

This happens no matter what time I put into the parameter. I've tried `Duration(1, "seconds")` and it's the same thing. Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you printed/debuged the timestamp before the `schedule` and when the `pollData` is called?

Comment: I've edited the question with that information. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try importing `scala.concurrent.duration._` and changing "millis" to milliseconds, without quotation marks so it isn't a string. I think due to incorrect imports the string "millis" may not be used and the default argument is used instead.

Comment: Hmmm...That doesn't even compile. I don't think that's the issue, because I tried shifting things over to java's scheduledThreadPoolExecutor, and I encountered the same issue. No matter what I do, it's only calling it every ten seconds. Thanks.

Comment: Oh my God! I'm an idiot! The reason for this problem, I just realized, is because in `PollSQSDataToDatabase` I'm long-polling an Amazon SQS database and, if it's empty, I wait 10 seconds for a reply. I just completely forgot about this, and was only searching for issues with the concurrency. I appreciate you taking the time though to help me out.

Comment: The API says the scheduler is created with a LoggingAdapter but doesn't say if there is an easy way to get trace info (like setting a property to see when tasks are run and complete).